# image to text not working - Text Recognizer is not operational

Tags: android

I am learning how to implement image to text in my app, I have been following multiple tutorials. But the problem always ends the same that the textRecognizer is not operational.

I have added the google play services in my gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1'`

I have read this that: The first time that an app using barcode and/or face APIs is installed on a device, GMS will download libraries to the device in order to do barcode and face detection. Usually this is done by the installer before the app is run for the first time. But somehow it does not work

This is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gin.scantext">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr"/>
</application>
```

This is my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
    } else {

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                RequestCameraPermissionID);
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (items.size() != 0) {
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }
                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr"/>
```